# IntelliJ shortcut location?

Tags: apt, unity, android, shortcuts, intellij

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I installed IntelliJ, Android Studio and Unity3D

Now Unity3D used a .deb file and thus is listed in the dpkg and apt, and Android Studio, while not coming in a deb file, created a shortcut into /usr/share/applications, so I get how the x11 and Unity (the desktop GUI) is able to show it when I search for it. But I can search for IntelliJ, and the search bar does show it as an application, but I was not able to find it either in apt nor the /usr/share/applications folder, so I'm simply wondering how the GUI knows that it is installed.

Comment: Putting "solved" in the title is not needed. Instead, mark your answer as "Accepted", and that will effectively mark the question as "solved". You may have to wait a few days before you can accept the answer.

Comment: Oh well now I can for some reasons. I really could not accept my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two applications folder that X11 (I assume) is looking into: `/usr/share/applications` AND `~/.local/share/applications`. I found the shortcut in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: So the shortcut was in ~/.local/share/applications? Just clarifying.

Comment: Indeed it was, I checked